# How to make my ImageView as an Image from URL and How to fix my code?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I want to make my ImageView as an image from an url, the apk successfully build but when i try to launch the imageView, the apps get crash. So how to fix my problem?

This is my java code:

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String imageUrl = "http://www.travelstar1.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Nice-view-of-the-Earth-from-space-51.jpg";

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    try {
        ImageView i = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iklanpertama);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return view;
}
```

}

and this is my layout code(xml), how to fix it?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iklanpertama"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff3e0"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:textColor="#212326"


    />
```

Comment: set this android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @Himani what do you mean?

Comment: Use Picasso or Glide, it is easier and safer

Comment: @Himani still crashing

Comment: @Nikoloz when i try to import picasso library, thats unsuccesfull or getting error

Comment: @MajuSumanto that's weird. What's error message?

Comment: @NikolozAkhvlediani Error:(3, 0) Could not find property 'dep' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@279de0bf.
<a href="openFile:D:\Informatics\AndroidApps\MyApplication\picasso\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: It seems like you have formatting error in gradle file, check it out. There can be mistyping, but i am not sure

Comment: @NikolozAkhvlediani the problem come up when i try to import module, android studio give me a message like above message. So i dont think the problem is error formatting in gradle file. Because i dont edit the gradle file.

Comment: Did you add picasso in depenedencies in gradle file? use this line: compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
If you did it, i don't have answer then.

Comment: i already added your line, but android studio give me a message: 
Error:(3, 0) Could not find property 'dep' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@71d5a575.
<a href="openFile:D:\Informatics\AndroidApps\MyApplication\picasso\build.gradle">Open File</a>
@NikolozAkhvlediani